# Is there a ruby equivalent to the PHP spl_autload_register?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In PHP, I use the spl_autoload_register function a lot. It allows you to load classes on demand as they are referenced. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mimic the PHP `__autoload()` behavior (like defining a classname to filename algotithm and requiring it) by redefining the `Object#const_missing` method, which is called when a constant (like a classname) is not found.

[Here there's an example.](http://rubychallenger.blogspot.com/2011/03/ruby-autoload-like-in-php.html)

(UPDATE: I've updated the link above.)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has two autoload mechanism: explicit and implicit.

The first is based on the `autoload` method. You can find a detailed description [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html).

```
autoload :Command,            'thin/command'
autoload :Connection,         'thin/connection'
autoload :Daemonizable,       'thin/daemonizing
```

The second is based on file names. Assuming the path `/path/to/folder` is in your `$LOAD_PATH`, then Ruby will try to load the file matching the required class name downcase and with underscore.

For instance, when you first use the `DefaultLogger` class, Ruby will try to find if

```
/path/to/folder/default_logger.rb
```

exists and defines Post. If so, the file will be loaded, along with the class definition. This approach is largely used when creating Gems.

Comment: Thanks for the info. With spl_autoload_register, I can register the my_custom_class_loader function to be fired if an undefined class is used. In this function, I can use custom logic (such as a particular naming convention) to load the required class file. Is this possible in ruby?

Comment: No, it isn't. In ruby it's a common practice to use `begin / rescue LoadError` statement.